# JEST with Angular SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

ProjectDir\node_modules\lodash-es\lodash.js:10
export { default as add } from './add.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
at Object. (../../node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs:5:23)

Comment: This question has already been answered. Jest runs with node, there for `import/export` brokeup the node process eather change them import/export to require

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this error following the link below with some variations, but the way that solved my problem was to add the following configuration to the "jset.config.js" file:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  "lodash-es": "lodash",
}
```

[Jest setup "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260218/jest-setup-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export)

Comment: That's replace the import, that's not a fix, it's merely a workaround