# Jest TypeScript tests failing with: export default data; ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to add tests to an existing React TypeScript App.

But every time I run the tests, it's failing with this error:

> /node_modules/@iconify/icons-eva/menu-2-fill.js:6
>
> export default data;
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
>
> ```
>   1 | import { Icon } from "@iconify/react";
> > 2 | import menu2Fill from "@iconify/icons-eva/menu-2-fill";
>     | ^
>   3 | import { alpha, styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
>   4 | import { Box, Stack, AppBar, Toolbar, IconButton } from "@mui/material";
>   5 |
>
>  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
>  at Object.<anonymous> (src/layouts/dashboard/DashboardNavbar.tsx:2:1)
> ```

Referred to [Jest setup "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260218/jest-setup-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export) and tried to add `moduleNameMapper` and `transformIgnorePatterns` to my `jest.config.js` file. This is how it looks.

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */

module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  verbose: true,
  transform: {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js",
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts",

  moduleNameMapper: {
    "@iconify/icons-eva/(.*)$": "@iconify/react/dist/$1",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@iconify)"],
};
```

It stills fails.

This is what my `package.json` file looks like in case that helps:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.3",
    "@iconify/icons-eva": "^1.2.0",
    "@iconify/icons-ic": "^1.2.0",
    "@iconify/react": "^3.1.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.4.1",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.68",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.1",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.4.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.46",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.14",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.22",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "change-case": "^4.1.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.6",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.6",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1"
  }
}
```