# JEST - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' with uuid library

Tags: typescript, jestjs, babeljs, puppeteer, nest

I used to solve similar errors while I was using Jest with only JavaScript, but currently I'm not able to do so with Typescript.

All my tests were running fine until I installed Puppeteer which requires `@types/jest-environment-puppeteer`, `@types/puppeteer` and `@types/expect-puppeteer`.

After installing them, puppeteer tests are running perfectly, but other tests started to fail with below error.

```
  D:\...\api\node_modules\uuid\dist\esm-browser\index.js:1    
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export { default as v1 } from './v1.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^  

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1796:14)   
      at Object.require (../node_modules/@nestjs/common/decorators/core/injectable.decorator.js:4:16)
```

**WHAT I DID?**

`allowJs: true` on `tsconfig.json` and set the `transformIgnorePatterns` on jest configs. So that jest can compile files from `node_modules/`
After that this error stopped but test failed for another strange reason.
And worse is that test start time have increased too much.

So I left `allowJs` as in original setup and updated jest config from

```
"transform": {
   "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
}
```

to

```
"transform": {
   "^.+\\.(t)s$": "ts-jest"
}
```

So currently ts-jest doesnt compile js files. But I think I am not able to make babel pick the transformation for `js` files. These are my jest configs:

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t)s$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": ["<rootDir>/node_modules/.+.(js|jsx)$"]
}
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Thanks to this reply:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54117206/15741905

I started googling for similar fixes and ended up here:
https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/issues/451

And this solved my problem: https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/issues/451#issuecomment-1112328417

```
// jest.config.js
{
//................
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Force module uuid to resolve with the CJS entry point, because Jest does not support package.json.exports. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/issues/451
    "uuid": require.resolve('uuid'),
  }
}
```

Tough I would still be happy if there is solution to this by using jest-babel.

Because I had to carry jest configs from `package.json` to a seperate `.js` file.

Edit:
According to this [github issue](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/issues/451#issuecomment-1206284480) compatibility issue has been solved with the latest release of the `uuid` library.

Comment: I was using a `jest.config.ts` file and the quotes kept getting stripped off `"uuid"` and the fix didn’t work. By making it `"^uuid$"` this started working for me. As of Aug 23, 2022 the latest version of uuid is still beta and the linked not above indicates it was only tested with the beta 29.x of jest so  I think since I'm just now upgrading from 27.x I'll stick with this solution for now. Thanks.

Comment: you welcome. i understand you very well :)

Answer (score 35):

Simply adding `moduleNameMapper:{"^uuid$": "uuid"}` into my jest.config.js fixed the issue for me:

Transitive dependency **uuid**: ^8.3.2

**jest**: 28.1.3

**angular**: 14.0.1

Comment: Not `uuid` but this answer helped with the `chevrotain` package which has the same issue

Answer (score 3):

**Upgrade to uuidv4() version 9.0.0 ("uuid": "^9.0.0") now fixes the the issue.** See comment from SimenB: https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/issues/451#issuecomment-1377099565

I tried the answer above initially, adding moduleNameMapper:{"^uuid$": "uuid"} into my jest.config.js, which fixed the issue for me. Then I followed the link (above) to read more and I saw that it has been fixed in "uuid": "^9.0.0".

So I took out the fix, installed latest uuidv4() at version 9.0.0, (package link below) and it started working fine again. No more errors and tests are running fine, again. https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

My React App started having the issues after updating "jest": "26.0.1" to "jest": "29.4.1", "environment-jsdom-fifteen": "1.0.2" to "jest-environment-jsdom": "29.4.1". along with other updates "ts-jest": "26.5.6" to "ts-jest": "^29.0.5". However, as mentioned above, upgrading to uuid version 9.0.0 has fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

> Date : 2/15/2023

> Jest Version :  "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",

> UUID Version :  "uuid": "^9.0.0"

using the `jest.config.ts` will generate an error that says

> Multiple configurations found

here's how you can override that

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../src/App';
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});

jest.mock('uuid', () => {
  return {
    v4: jest.fn(() => 1)
  }
})
```

Hoping this will solve other peoples error if the correct answer is not working for you :).

Answer (score 0):

adding this to the package.json file solved it for me:

```
"devDependencies": {
....
},
"browser": {
    "uuid": "./node_modules/uuid/dist/esm-browser/index.js"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@damdafayton's answer partially worked for me (thank you), but it ended up causing problems with another library that uses `uuid` (in my case, `mongoose`).  I think the override was causing `mongoose` to pick up the wrong version.

To overcome the game of whack-a-mole, I ended up creating a mock for `uuid` in my top-level `__mocks__/uuid.js` containing:

```
const uuid = require('../node_modules/uuid/dist');
module.exports = uuid;
```

...which seems to do the trick.

It may be that I'm more specifically forcing the version of `uuid` for jest, not interrupting the normal resolver, but it's hard to be certain.