# jest moduleNameMapper fixes unexpected token 'export' now breaks relative module import

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm using create-react-app, with `ts-jest` and I'm trying to use the `microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk` npm package. The error I get is:

```
Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

/node_modules/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/node_modules/uuid/dist/esm-browser/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export { default as v1 } from './v1.js';

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1449:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/distrib/lib/src/common/src/common/Guid.ts:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/distrib/lib/src/common/src/common/PlatformEvent.ts:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/distrib/lib/src/common/AudioSourceEvents.js:20:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/distrib/lib/src/common/Exports.js:15:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/distrib/lib/src/sdk/src/sdk/LogLevel.ts:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/distrib/lib/src/common.browser/src/common.browser/ConsoleLoggingListener.ts:6:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/distrib/lib/src/common.browser/Exports.js:15:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/distrib/lib/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/<component-name>.tsx:1:1)
```

I can solve this error, as supplied by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73203803

```
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "uuid": require.resolve('uuid'),
    },
```

However it looks like `@mswjs` is erroring because it has a reference to a `utils/uuid.ts` and that is getting mapped by the root module mapper.

```
TypeError: uuid_1.uuidv4 is not a function
          at new IsomorphicRequest (<root>/node_modules/@mswjs/interceptors/src/IsomorphicRequest.ts:40:15)
```

Does this mean I can't use `@mswjs`? Is there a configuration I can update to allow for this to work? I'm not totally clear no steps forward, any guidance would be helpful.

I've tried a number of `jest.config` permutations

```
    moduleNameMapper: {
        // this file has to https://stackoverflow.com/a/73203803
        "uuid": require.resolve('uuid'),
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!@mswjs)/"],
```

Here's my current `.jest.config.cjs`

```js
module.exports = {
    extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts", ".tsx"],
    transform: {
        ".(ts|tsx)": "ts-jest",
        // ".(js|jsx)": "babel-jest",
    },
    // transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!@mswjs)/"],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        // this file has to https://stackoverflow.com/a/73203803
        "uuid": require.resolve('uuid'),
    },
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"],
    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx"],
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        "**/*.ts",
        "**/*.tsx",
        "!**/*.d.ts",
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
module.exports = {
  // other config options...
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/(?!uuid).+\\.js$"
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^uuid$": "uuid/dist/esm-browser/index.js"
  },
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
  }
};
```

This configuration tells Jest to:

1. Ignore transforming all JS files in the “node_modules” directory,
   except for the “uuid” package.
2. Map the “uuid” package to its ESM
   code, so that Jest can recognize its “export” statements.
3. Transform
   all JS files (except for “uuid”) using Babel, which will convert the
   ESM code into CJS code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `moduleNameMapper` as it takes any import with `uuid` and even than `IsomorphicRequest` is using its own  `import { uuidv4 } from './utils/uuid'` jest is trying to resolve it with `require.resolve('uuid')` You can change that by asking jest to resolve only modules that starts with `uuid` just add `^`:

```
 moduleNameMapper: {
    "^uuid": require.resolve('uuid'),
 },
```