# Jest cannot parse a file even after transpiling is configured

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have written a simple test case where I am trying to render a single component, and get a snapshot. When I try to run it, I get an error message `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`. Full error message is -

```
    D:\Work\Fradium\Repos\reactor\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\ScrollView\AndroidHorizontalScrollContentViewNativeComponent.js:9
    export var __INTERNAL_VIEW_CONFIG = {
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

       7 |
       8 | import { FC } from "react";
    >  9 | import { View, Text } from "tamagui";
         | ^
      10 |
      11 | type TestComponentProps = {
      12 |   message: string;

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
      at Object.require (../../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js:39:1)
      at requireActual (../../node_modules/react-native/jest/mockComponent.js:15:12)
      at mockComponent (../../node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:148:27)
      at Object.require [as ScrollView] (../../node_modules/react-native/index.js:158:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@tamagui/scroll-view/src/ScrollView.tsx:6:52)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@tamagui/scroll-view/src/index.ts:1:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@tamagui/sheet/src/SheetScrollView.tsx:19:32)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@tamagui/sheet/src/createSheet.tsx:55:9)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@tamagui/sheet/src/Sheet.tsx:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@tamagui/sheet/src/index.ts:1:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@tamagui/dialog/src/Dialog.tsx:88:41)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@tamagui/dialog/src/index.ts:1:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@tamagui/alert-dialog/src/AlertDialog.tsx:45:90)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@tamagui/alert-dialog/src/index.ts:1:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/tamagui/src/index.ts:5:15)
      at Object.require (src/components/TestComponent/index.tsx:9:1)
      at Object.require (src/components/index.ts:11:1)
      at Object.require (src/index.ts:10:1)
      at Object.require (__tests__/components/TestComponent.test.tsx:2:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Tests:       0 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.546 s
Ran all test suites.
```

This is my test -

```
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import { TestComponent } from "../..";

describe("Test component", () => {
  test("renders correctly", () => {
    const tree = renderer
      .create(<TestComponent message="Test string"></TestComponent>)
      .toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Furthermore, I have gone through several posts explaining how some libraries require jest transpiling them to the lower versions of CommonJS. This is what I have in my `transformIgnorePatterns` in my `jest.config.js` -

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
  "node_modules/(?!(" +
    "(jest-)?react-native(-.*)?" +
    "|@react-native(-community)?" +
    "|tamagui" +
    "|@tamagui/.*" +
    "|expo(nent)?" +
    "|@expo(nent)?/.*" +
    "|@expo-google-fonts/.*" +
    "|react-navigation" +
    "|@react-navigation/.*" +
    "|react-native-svg" +
    ")/)",
],
```

I have included `react-native` in my transform ignore patterns, but still jest is not able to transpile the above mentioned file. Is the error because of the transpiling issue with these files or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest setup "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260218/jest-setup-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. It's one of the first answers I referred to, and this seems to be a very similar issue. Additionally, I got to [this](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/unit-testing/#configuration) link through that answer, but still no luck.

Comment: I've also mentioned in the question that my `transformIgnorePatterns` is set to appropriate regex (in my opinion) for the job. The post that you mentioned helped me understand how the config works, but I could not resolve my error with any of the answers mentioned there.